New install 24.04: Thunderbird cannot send emails
I have Ubuntu 22.04 still installed on one partition and I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 on another partition.

I've been using Thunderbird happily for a long time, most recently version 115.13.0 on my Ubuntu 22.04 partition.
I installed Thunderbird on the new 24.04 partition too, version 128.0esr. It correctly reads my emails (through imap), but it cannot send emails, save drafts or mark emails as read on the server.

So Thunderbird 115 works perfectly but Thunderbird 128 doesn't on the same GMail account (same problem with another non-GMail account). I checked the smtp settings carefully, they are identical.
It's possible I made a mistake, but I'm at a loss about what is going wrong. How can I diagnose and solve this problem?

A big difference is that thunderbird is now installed as a snap in 24.04

Thank you, so I could try to install the apt package instead I guess. But there must also be something wrong in my config, so I'd like to understand if possible.

you may find some help on this here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1235488

Perhaps 1) notice where your thunderbird mail box(es) are. 2) set aside ~/.thunderbird 3) change your thunderbird installation away from SNAP.  Finally 4) start thunderbird - which will now require that you either start a new profile OR, say specifically where the existing profile(s)  [is|are] - that's whey you notices where the existing profile(s) were in step 1.

@graham thanks, but I'm confident my smtp settings are correct since they work in the 22.04 version.

@quill I will try this if nothing else works, but I'd like to understand what is wrong currently if possible.

If you'd like, I can post the procedure I use to install the Thunderbird from a tar ball.  I don't even have to remove the SNAP package.  Even if SNAP does update it's package, it's isolated and ignored.

What I did has worked many times. In the TB version which is working well, go to the hamburger menu, select Export and save the file. In the new instance of TB, follow the same path but this time Import the file you saved earlier.

Thank you both for your ideas, but I doubt that my problem comes from this specific version of Thunderbird, or at if it does I'd like to know what causes it.

In case anybody is interested, I ended up removing the Thunderbird snap package and installing the Mozilla apt package. This installed Thunderbird 115.13.0 in 24.04, it solved the issue.
I'm disappointed that I didn't find any better solution: after all, isn't the snap version of Thunderbird supposed to be able to send emails too?
To change from snap to Mozilla apt, I followed this but with one more step:

First, add the PPA by Mozilla Team.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa


Then, copy and paste the following code in a terminal in one go (don't copy-paste line by line) to prioritize the apt version of thunderbird over the snap version.
echo '
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: thunderbird
Pin: version 2:1snap*
Pin-Priority: -1
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/thunderbird


Next, remove the snap version of thunderbird.
sudo snap remove thunderbird


Remove the transitional package from apt (otherwise apt says the package is already installed):
sudo apt remove thunderbird


Install Thunderbird with apt.
sudo apt install thunderbird


To ensure that unattended upgrades do not reinstall the snap version of Thunderbird, enter the following command.
echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-thunderbird



